# Not able to format NFC card using NdefFormatable

Tags: android, tags, format, nfc, ndef

I am using NdefFormatable class to format my NFC card. The code is like:

```
NdefFormatable formatable=NdefFormatable.get(tag);
```

But i get formatable reference as null. I checked the code that is run inside the get(tag) method. It checks:

```
if (!tag.hasTech(TagTechnology.NDEF_FORMATABLE)) return null;
```

I ran *"tag.getTechList()"* for my tag. I got:

```
android.nfc.tech.NfcA
android.nfc.tech.Ndef
```

I was able to format this card using Trigger application.

What can be done to format this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `NdefFormatable` and the `Ndef` tag technologies are mutually exclusive. Either your tag is not yet NDEF formatted (i.e. it is not yet prepared to store NDEF messages) or it is already prepared to store NDEF messages (and already contains (at least an empty) an NDEF message).

So `NdefFormatable` is only used for writing an initial NDEF message to a tag.

As your tag already lists the `android.nfc.tech.Ndef` technology, it is already prepared to store an NDEF message and does not need further formatting. You can simply overwrite (given that the tag is not read-only) any existing NDEF message by using the `writeNdefMessage()` method of the `Ndef` object. E.g. to "format" the tag to an empty NDEF message, you could do something like:

```
Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(tag);
ndefTag.writeNdefMessage(new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_EMPTY, null, null, null)));
```

---

**Update:**
On devices with the libnfc-nci NFC stack, it seems that `NdefFormatable` and `Ndef` tag technologies are no longer mutually exclusive. Formatted tags will (sometimes?) be enumerated as both `NdefFormatable` and `Ndef`. In thoses cases, you would still typically try to use the `Ndef` first and only if that fails use the `NdefFormatable` object.

Comment: Thanks Micheal. It would really help if you could also provide some info about, how to format an tag to NDEF format, that is not currently in NDEF format.

Comment: @jsbisht You mean one that neither lists `Ndef` nor `NdefFormatable` as its tag technologies?

Comment: Yes, a tag thats not in NDEF or NDEFFormatable format.

Comment: @jsbisht A complete answer to this would clearly be to broad for that format. The short answer is: It's not that simple. You would first need to discover what tag you are dealing with (through extensive fingerprinting), and then (if the tag even permits/supports this) you would need to apply that specific technology's method to format it into an NFC Forum tag (according to the NFC Forum's Type X Tag Operation specifications).

Comment: That makes sense. I was hoping that there might be some generic way to deal with tags. Looks like i should just stick with NDEF tags. Thanks :)

Comment: In fact, that's one of the reasons why NFC tags (e.g. NXP NTAG series) usually come preformatted for NDEF.

Comment: @MichaelRoland when `ndef == null` I'm trying to format the tag. Tag is ndefFormattable, but `formattable.format()` throws `IOexception`

Answer (score 0):

Your device cannot *format* the tag to NDEF. Otherwise you would have gotten `android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable` in the tech list.

But you can still read and write in NDEF format to the tag.

I am guessing Trigger just writes an empty message to the Ndef tag.

Comment: Thanks Gak2. I still believe there would be some way to format a NFC tag, apart from using an empty message.